# Const and Static declared in a Class, C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

I know the class is a description so we can't define const in it. But I find it make me puzzled ,First:

```
 class A
{
   private:
          const int Months=12;// Fails
};
```

I don't know if I am right that I think if there may be many  objects of A ,there will be many const Months. So C++ forbid it.

but Second:

```
class A
{
  private:
       static int Montshs =12;//Fails,
};
```

I also know Months can be initialized out of class A;
I think it's a description so we can't use static and initialize in class A.(I don't know wether I am right),

but go on:

```
class A
{
  private:
       static const int Montshs =12;//ok, 
};
```

This will be OK ,and I can't give myself somereason. Can anyone be kind enough to tell me the reason?

Is there anyone can give me detailed explanations about these three problems?
I think maybe it is about the arrangement of menmory.

Comment: Note that the first one is valid in the current standard (C++11).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1: `const int Months=12;`
  This was not allowed in C++03, but is allowed since C++11. The reasons were exactly what you described: There may be many instances of A, so this is not one single value but has to be written into any object of class A. In C++11 this notation is used to give that nonstatic member a default value. In C++03 you had to remember to initialize the member in each constructor.
- 2: `static int Months =12;` This still is a *variable* which has to be defined in a single translation unit. So in one single X.cpp there *has* to be a line `int A::Months = 42;`. That way, the variable gets the value you initialize it with (42 in this case), making the value you give it in the declaration (the 12) pretty useless.
- 3: `static const int Montshs =12;` This is a special case, because it's a *compiletime constant*. It is *one* value, not bound to any single object of type `A`, and not changeable. Therefore the compiler benefits from seeing the definition in the header, because it can optimize away any erferences to the symbol, basically using the value 12 wherever it sees `A::Months`. It basically does not need to allocate storage for it, because it can write the value 12 into the code wherever needed. This was not always possible either, some older compilers would not accept it. You then would have to go with the enum-Trick: `enum { Months = 12 };`

Comment: You should add that `constexpr` may and should be used with possibility 3.

Answer (score 2):

This is all explained in detail [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#in-class)

> So why do these inconvenient restrictions exist? A class is typically
>   declared in a header file and a header file is typically included into
>   many translation units. However, to avoid complicated linker rules,
>   C++ requires that every object has a unique definition. That rule
>   would be broken if C++ allowed in-class definition of entities that
>   needed to be stored in memory as objects.

In C++11 theses restrictions are [lifted](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init).

> The basic idea for C++11 is to allow a non-static data member to be
>   initialized where it is declared (in its class).